# how to call the global function in union statement

Tags: json, postgresql

Hi i wrote one union function in that function have to call a another function. how to call one function in union function below the my code

fn_get_project_files is a function but i don't know how to call in below union function

i declared a new function into variable and tha type is json and this variable union wih below code but the returun  the data of the variable not getting,remng 2union data is getting output.

```
declare v_project_attachment json
v_project_attachment =(select array_to_json(array_agg(row_to_json(b))) FROM (select public.fn_get_project_files(ip_company_id,ip_created_by) )b);

(select array_to_json(array_agg(row_to_json(b))) FROM
        
     (select array_to_json(array_agg(row_to_json(b))) FROM (select public.fn_get_project_files(ip_company_id,ip_created_by) )b) as project_attachments,
      
                         (select * from public."VOfficeApp_filefolder" vff
                           where vff.created_by = ip_created_by
                           and   vff.company_id = ip_company_id
                           and vff.folder_name != ip_company_folder_name
                           and vff.status = 'Active'
                          and is_conference = false **example:(o/p =1)**
                          union 
                          select * from public."VOfficeApp_filefolder" vff
                           where  
                           vff.company_id = ip_company_id
                           and vff.folder_name != ip_company_folder_name
                           and vff.status = 'Active'
                          and is_conference = true **example:(o/p =2)**
                          union
                          select * from v_project_attachment  **example:(o/p=3)**
                         )b)as folder

Actual output = (1,2) what i am getting the output
Expected output =(1,2,3)
```

Comment: Your question isn't very clear, and your example code is quite hard to read. I can see a call to a function `public.fn_get_project_files`; is this what you're having problems with? Are you getting some kind of error? Or is there some change you want to make to this function, but don't know how? Please click [edit] and try to be as specific as possible about the problem, but leave out details that _aren't_ relevant to the problem - maybe make a simpler [mcve] rather than showing real code from your application.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: Postgres 9.3 and 9.4 are [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  you should plan an upgrade as soon as possible.

Comment: fn_get_project_files  is function and how this function call in union statement

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name fn_get_project_files is function and how this function call in union statement

Comment: @IMSoP  fn_get_project_files is function and how this function call in union statement

Comment: OK, but *what exactly is the problem*? What have you tried, and what happened when you ran it? Did you get an error? Did the function not do what you wanted? Can you come up with a shorter piece of code which is easier to read, but still demonstrates the issue (a [mcve])? Don't try to fit details into this comment area, click [edit] and try to make the question as clear as possible for someone who has never seen your code before. Ideally, a short piece of code the reader could run themselves, and the exact output you wanted and got for that specific code.

Comment: @IMSoP i declared a new function into variable and that type is json and this variable union with below code but the return the data of the variable not getting,remng 2union data is getting output.  Modified the question

Comment: Your code is still completely impossible for anyone else to run, and really hard to read. One of your edits removed the first few lines of the function declaration, so what's left isn't even valid SQL; you've got references to tables, functions, and inputs which you haven't shown us; and there's a whole load of nested queries and `array_to_json(array_agg(row_to_json(b)))` which I have no idea if they're anything to do with the problem, or just real application code you haven't simplified. Try to come up with an example that _you have actually run_ and _someone reading could run themselves_.